# WooCommerce, Add to cart not working, and cart page not displaying

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am fairly new to WooCommerce and although the other day the add to cart and cart page was displaying fine. I am now finding that going to my cart page brings up a blank page.

Does anyone know what can cause this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about your cart page url?
Did you alredy set the permalink in wordpress?

Settings > Permalink Settings > Post name

it's automatic to show /%postname%/

Answer (score 0):

add this code into your function.php:

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'my_expiration_filter', 99, 3);
function my_expiration_filter($seconds, $user_id, $remember){
//if "remember me" is checked;
if ( $remember ) {
    //WP defaults to 2 weeks;
    $expiration = 14*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
} else {
    //WP defaults to 48 hrs/2 days;
    $expiration = 2*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
}

//http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem
if ( PHP_INT_MAX - time() < $expiration ) {
    //Fix to a little bit earlier!
    $expiration =  PHP_INT_MAX - time() - 5;
}

return $expiration;
```

}

Comment: add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'my_expiration_filter', 99, 3); 
function my_expiration_filter($seconds, $user_id, $remember){
if ( $remember ) {
    $expiration = 14*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
} else {
    $expiration = 2*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
}
if ( PHP_INT_MAX - time() < $expiration ) {
    $expiration =  PHP_INT_MAX - time() - 5;
}
return $expiration;
}